# Using PowerApps AzureServiceBus connector SendMessage ContentData

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azureservicebus, powerapps, sendmessage

The PowerApps - Azure Service Bus Connector function that I am trying to use is defined as:

```
ServiceBus.SendMessage(EntityName:Text, {systemProperties :Text, ContentData:Blob, ContentType:Text, Properties:Table, MessageId:Text, To:Text, ReplyTo:Text, ReplyToSesionId:Text, Label:Text, ScheduledEnquequeTimeUtc:DateTime, SessionId:Text, CorrelationId:Text, SequenceNumber:Number, LockToken:Text, TimeToLive:Text})
```

As you can see ContentData is of type Blob, and PowerApps seems unable to convert a text string to a blob. So although the below will send a message, the content is empty on inspection in either the service bus explorer or a receiving application. Note that the Properties table data and Label value can be seen in the received message.

```
ServiceBus.SendMessage("TestTopic",{ContentData:"HelloWorld", Label:"MyLabel", Properties:Table({key:"MyUserDefinedKey",value:"MyUserDefinedKeyValue"})})
```

Is there anyway to directly populate the ContentData with text? I was hoping to use a PowerApp text input.

I have tried changing the ContentType and ContentData to various options without success.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#send-message), the data type for `ContentData` is `bytes` which I don't believe PowerApps supports (find supported data types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/data-types)).

**One thing to try would be**: `ContentData: JSON("Hello World", JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData)`

This is the only way I know of to handle binary data in PowerApps but I'm unsure if it will encode text.

Answer (score 0):

You can send custom properties in a Power Apps Service Bus connector SendMessage call using the Properties parameter.  The Properties parameter takes a Table with specific rows of key and value pairs.

I didn't find the ContentData parameter well documented.  In my testing it takes a data URI string value with mandatory base64 encoding.  Unfortunately there is no built in way to base64 encode in a canvas Power App.  If the parameter value isn't properly formatted the resulting Servivce Bus queue message will have an empty ContentData value. Below is an example that sends a new message to the queue, setting the broker property: Label, and three custom properties, along with the text "Hello world!" in the ContentData parameter.

Example:

```
ServiceBus.SendMessage("p1imagecaptureevents",
{ContentType:"text/plain"
 ,Properties:Table (
    {key: "Label", value: "labelvalue2"}, 
    {key: "myFirstFieldName", value: "'My first field's value8'"}, 
    {key: "mySecondFieldName", value: "My second field's value5"}, 
    {key: "myOtherFieldName", value: "More values5"})
 ,ContentData:"data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh"  // "Hello world!" base64 encoded text
})
```